# Why does camlp4o fail to parse (or) as a binary function?

Tags: ocaml, camlp4

In vanilla OCaml, `(or)` is a binary function just like `(+)` and all the others, so code like this works fine:

```
let any (truths:bool list) = List.fold_left (or) false truths
```

But in any environment where camlp4o is loaded, this fails to parse with:

```
Error: Parse error: ")" or "module" or [expr] expected after "(" (in [expr])
```

Meanwhile, `(+)` and the other integer arithmetic operators continue to work as expected in either environment:

```
let sum (nums:int list) = List.fold_left (+) 0 nums
```

Why is this? Is this a limitation with camlp4o, or a bug? This occurs on OCaml 3.12.1 (on OS X 10.7.4, installed freshly via GODI bootstrap).

Answer (score 4):

This is [a known bug](http://caml.inria.fr/mantis/view.php?id=5495) that has been fixed since. The soon to be released 4.00 version will not have that issue.

PS: when I find something suspicious about OCaml that I strongly suspect is a bug, my technique is to do a google search with the `site:caml.inria.fr/mantis` modifier to search the OCaml bugtracker for similar content.

Answer (score 1):

In "normal" OCaml you can use `(or)` interchangeably with `(||)`.  If you look at the definition of the [revised syntax](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-camlp4/manual007.html), the use of `(or)` is not supported.  You always need to use `(||)`.  Perhaps this is a side effect of that change?

At any rate, some quick tests indicate that `(||)` works with camlp4o.